# Why element with position:absolute is put behind ::after pseudo-element

Tags: html, css

I am new to HTML and CSS and as I was doing some exercises, I faced an issue, that is, I wanted to create website with blur effect and thus I created header with class showcase and inside header I created div with class content.

```
<header class="showcase">
        <div class="content">
<img src="img/pexels-photo-373912.jpeg" alt="Photo">
<h2 class="title">Welcome </h2>
<p class="text">Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque, quidem!</p>
        </div>
    </header>
```

Then with css ::after pseudo-element I created background-image:

```
.showcase::after{
    content:"";
    background-image: url(img/action-america-architecture-378570.jpg);
    background-size:cover;
background-position: center;
height: 100vh;
filter: blur(10px);
display: block;
transition: 1000ms;

}
```

So, the problem is when I change position of div with class content to absolute

```
.content{
    position: absolute;
}
```

then that div is put behind ::after background-image. As I know ::after or ::before has position of static by default thus it has to be vice versa behind .content with position:absolute. Am I correct?

Comment: can you share all the CSS/HTML so we can reprduce it

Comment: @TemaniAfif, hi dude, I just wanted to understand why position:absolute is stacked behind ::after

Comment: I am trying to add an answer ;) the short one is: it's the filter (remove it and see)

Comment: ok found a duplicate .. all happen here : https://www.w3.org/TR/css-position-3/#painting-order at the point (8) and filter behave like opacity there. So position element are rendred before filtred/transformed/with opacity element

Comment: @TemaniAfif, you were right Temani, if I remove filter then position:absolute is stacked on ::after. Can you explain what happens behind the scenes?:)

Comment: @TemaniAfif, ok Temani I have read the link you gave and honestly, I have problems with English thus can you please very briefly explain. I really hope for your help:)

Comment: to make it short and easy: without the filter we first paint the *normal* element (in your case the pseudo element) then the positioned ones which is what you are expecting .. but adding the filter to our element will make it behave differently and will be painted later above the positioned element .. so the filter change the painting order (replace with tranform or opacity and you will also have the same)

Answer (score 0):

use z-index property into content class, and it must be more than zero, Default is zero.

```
.content{
position: absolute;
z-index:2;
}
```

Comment: default is auto not 0 ... there is a big difference

Comment: @jumah Mohammadi, thank you dude for your attention, I just wanted to understand why position:absolute is behind ::after

Comment: @Mirich when you use Position with absolute value in a tag, then it will be Separated or Suspended From it's parent, and the last Element will be in front of others, so to control which one should be in front of, you should use z-index, the element that is bigger in z-index will be infront of others.